How can you display the time and date in Zig?
How can you display the time and date in Sun Sep 15 10:01:02 AM CEST 2024 format in Zig?
PS: just started learn Zig

Currently, date/time handling is not part of the Zig standard library. So you have 2 options basically, use C libraries (libc has all you need I think) or a third party Zig library. There are some out there, e.g. zeit, zig-time or zdt (disclaimer: I'm the author of zdt).

Here's an example with 3rd party libraries, zdt and zeit. Since the OP implicitly asks about timezones ("CEST"), I limit the example to libraries that handle those. Disclaimer: I'm the author of one of them, zdt.
const std = @import("std");
const zdt = @import("zdt"); // uses: tagged version 0.4.0
const zeit = @import("zeit"); // uses: tagged version 0.4.3

pub fn main() !void {
    // timezone rule files vary in size, so we need to allocate memory dynamically:
    var gpa = std.heap.GeneralPurposeAllocator(.{}){};
    defer _ = gpa.deinit();
    const allocator = gpa.allocator();

    // for string output:
    var formatted = std.ArrayList(u8).init(allocator);
    defer formatted.deinit();

    // zdt
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    const local_zone = try zdt.Timezone.tzLocal(allocator);
    defer local_zone.deinit();
    const now_loc = try zdt.Datetime.now(.{.tz=&local_zone});
    try now_loc.toString("%a %b %d %I:%M:%S %p %Z %Y", formatted.writer());
    std.debug.print("zdt:  {s}\n", .{formatted.items});
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------

    formatted.clearAndFree();

    // zeit
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    const local = try zeit.local(allocator, null);
    defer local.deinit();
    const now = try zeit.instant(.{});
    const now_local = now.in(&local);
    const dt_zeit = now_local.time();
    try dt_zeit.strftime(formatted.writer(), "%a %b %d %I:%M:%S %p %Z %Y");
    std.debug.print("zeit: {s}\n", .{formatted.items});
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
}

Notes:

for pure date/time, there are other libraries out there as well
also note that you'll need to tell the build system where and which version (commit, tag etc.) of the libraries to fetch in a .zon file and the build.zig
helpful in this context: Build System Tricks on ziggit.dev
you could also use C libraries, which can be integrated very well with Zig

